# ANT_HOME is set incorrectly or ant could not be located. Please set ANT_HOME

Tags: java, ant

I'm upgrading my ant to 1.9. But after I set the environment variables, this message printed in console:
ANT_HOME is set incorrectly or ant could not be located. Please set ANT_HOME.

I found some answers here and did accordingly, but all didn't work.

I tried `cd %ANT_HOME%` and `cd %ANT_HOME%\bin` and it shows the correct path, but I can't use ant command even in go to 'ANT_HOME'.

Following is my environment variables:

```
ANT_HOME: C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.9.4
PATH: %ANT_HOME%\bin
```

All set in system variables.

I checked all my settings and have no idea what's happening. Can anyone help with this?

Many thanks.

Comment: In command prompt, type `ant -version`, what is the output

Comment: The same error info. I checked the ant.bat file, and traced this error message, found  that this leads to here: if not exist "%ProgramFiles%\ant" So I tried to change my ant directory to 'ant', but another error occurs: Failed to locateorg.apache.tools.ant.Main.

Comment: tried rebooting your system..??

Comment: @ankur-singhal I rebooted my system. I've posted my answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the zip file I downloaded for ant is not correct. I got another one with `.tar.gz` as its extension then it works. @ankur-singhal Thanks for your help.